# PDF content extractor library for Android

Tags: android, pdf

Does anyone know a good Java library (for Android) to extract the text content in a PDF? I have used PDFClown with Java but I cannot use it with Android because Android does not have Java AWT support. Instead it uses android.graphics package.

I'm looking for Android library similar to PDFClown but I couldn't find it anywhere in the internet. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking library recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Android port of Apache's PDFBox at https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Hope it helps

Comment: can you help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047361/pdf-extracting-text