# Pdf Extracting text

Tags: android, pdf, intellij-idea, pdfbox

I want to select the path of my `pdf` file in

```
private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;
```

I have two buttons,one to get the path of the pdf file and the other to extraxt the text:

```
Button b1 = (Button) x.findViewById(R.id.buttonStripText);
        Button button = (Button) x.findViewById(R.id.pick);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stripText(v);
            }
        });
```

And the other two functions are

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(requestCode){
            case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                   fileName = data.getData().getPath();
                   System.out.println("Your File Name is:::"+fileName);
                }
                break;

        }
    }
    private void setup() {
        PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
    }
    public void stripText(View v) {
        String parsedText = null;
        try {

            PDDocument document  = PDDocument.load(assetManager.open("cover_letter.pdf"));
            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(0);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);
            parsedText = "Parsed text: " + pdfStripper.getText(document);
                if (document != null) document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        tv.setText(parsedText);
    }
```

I doesn't throw any error but also it doesn't get the extracted text.
This kind of `Dialog_Load_File` opens google drive,if possible to show me how to open internal storage!
Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are not using `fileName`. So what is this about?

Comment: I am not using filename cause the format is not as I want it to example `Android.filepath....cover_letter.pdf` ,the function itself is not working,cover_letter is in raw folder but still it doesnt extract the text

Comment: I even tried `String.getdirectory.R.raw.cover_letter` to try the function if it works but nothing gets extracted

Comment: Put it in the assets directory as your code uses the assets manager.

Comment: Of course that fileName is a non existing file system path.

Comment: My mission is to allow the user to load from an internal storage but it opens google drive

Comment: You already told that. Does not make any sense to repeat that. Instead you could have reacted to the point on comments.

Comment: what point?the fact that it is not in the asset folder?you are right,it is not

Comment: @greenapps it works if I put the pdf document in the assets folder,can you help me make it as I want

Comment: It is unclear what you ask now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(assetManager.open("cover_letter.pdf"));
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(... from any input stream .... );
```

So if you can open an inputstream from assets or raw or from file or from uri you are done.

For instance if you get an uri in onActivityResult

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load( is );
```

Comment: on click button to select a pdf file of users choice,but not from google drive but from internal storage and pass the url to `PDDocument document`

Comment: works perfectly but just tell me how to open that damn internal storage and not google drive

Comment: I dont know where you are talking about. Did you use a different intent? Just show both full urls. Uri.toString() values.

Comment: that is okay,just when the I click on the button Select PDF,it opens google drive.I want to open file explorer

Comment: Unclear. If you click the button the user can select a file. Its the user who determines if he selects a file from internal storage or sd card or gallery or dropbox or googele drive. After the selection onActivityResult is invoked. It is unclear when google drive is opened as you say. When exactly? In onActivityResult? There is no code who would open anything. You could much better explain what is happening.

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not open Google Drive.